# Best practice for application monitoring

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to create a monitoring application for our operations department to be proactive when dealing with systems that are encountering problems. I created an app that does the job but it has some draw backs:

1. Each copy of the app running serves individual pings to the systems, when 1 ping would suffice.
2. I have 3 different api's for getting the status of our systems depending whether its hosted IIS, WCF or desktop.

To fix the first issue i was going to create a database which an interim service(app)(monitor) would make the pings, then the app would query the database for updates. After thinking about this I realized the second issue and decided it is a future problem.

So my thought was to, rather than have the interim application pinging the systems, simply have each system have one interface in which it posts it status to the database every x time. But then I ran into a problem with the WCF and IIS services we have. These services can sit for days without anyone actually using the service. How would I make these services continue to post its data?

My questions are:

Is it better to have data REQUESTED or PUSHED in this type of situation?

If REQUESTED, what is a suggested practice for maintaining a single API across mulitple platforms(IIS, WCF, Desktop)?

If PUSHED, how would you handle the case of the Web services which are instance based and not continuously running?

Comment: There are tons of tools on the market to help you monitor the health of your running applications and infrastructure. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I dont know how these applications actually monitor my apps, my company is cheap, and we have needs beyond knowing it is running, such as knowing it is also properly communicating with x other devices/systems.

Comment: @daniel-mann is right. Don't reinvent the wheel. Look at some of the monitoring tools or services out there. They will probably meet most of your needs and you can add custom checks by writing your own scripts or apps to be used within one of those tools.

Comment: What if im looking to actually learn how to do these things and put them into practice rather than just using someone else's tool. The end result could be the same but I gain much more out of the process.

Comment: Does your **company** gain much more out of the process? It'd be a more efficient use of your time (and **their money**) to investigate the existing monitoring products (many of which are free) to see if you can integrate them with your product.

Comment: "My company is cheap" is another way of saying "My company doesn't realize that software takes time to write, and time is money". Anything you write yourself will almost certainly be less functional and cost more than licensing an appropriate tool.

Comment: I understand everyone's points, but they do not address my questions in any way. Yes i am trying to create an application that plenty of other people have made. This is a personal exercise to improve me abilities, not just assist my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For web services, one solution might be to implement a health-check end point , something that you can simply call like: webservice/isServiceUp?

I prefer that this information is PULLED. If a service / web Service/ Application is down, then you can't possibly rely on it to write something to the DB... it would be possible but highly risky and unreliable.

In a real world situation, it is a little more complicated than that because something might happen between your service host and the consumer (DNS problem for example), in which case, you would want to consider the case of not getting anything back from the isServiceUp (no true no false, just a 400 lvl error)...

Consider using your load balancer for checking on APPS / web services and proactively switching to a different IP in case of issues... it is a possibility.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I had forgotten about the case where an app cant push if it isnt running. Also I have a isServiceUp endpoint currently, my gripe with that is that endpoint is hosted differently depending on the application host type, IIS, WCF, Desktop

Comment: Eventually our goal is to remove our applications from IIS hosting and host them purely through WCF. Would it be strange to host 2 WCF services in a single application? One for my clients and one for internal uses?

Comment: If you do not need the flexibility of having each service with its own APP and therefore with its own app-pool (very handy for attaching a debugger). then i do not see an issue with that besides less clarity maybe. But at the end it is your call.